# Why does this cause a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, initialization

I have this code:

```
public class Sprite {
    protected float x;
    protected float y;
    protected Image image;
    protected Rectangle boundingBox;

    Sprite(float x, float y, Image image) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.image = image;
        boundingBox = new Rectangle(x, y, 
            this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight());
    }
```

...

```
public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
    return boundingBox;
}
```

However when I call this function in a different class once the sprite object has been defined and initialized:

```
public static boolean collides(Sprite object1, Sprite object2) {
    return object1.getBoundingBox().intersects(object2.getBoundingBox());
}
```

I get a null pointer exception, pointing to the line that contains this:

```
this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight());
```

Why is this?

Comment: Post the code where you call the `Sprite` constructor.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the correct Sprint constructor and not the default one with no params?  Are you making sure that the image being passed in isn't null in the constructor?  I'd add something like `if(image != null) {this.image = image} else { image = new Image()};` Also you'll want to make sure that x and y in image aren't null as well.

Comment: If you encounter a NullPointerException please always provide the stack trace... use a debugger to figure out which variable really is null.

Comment: Why did you accept hvgotcodes and not Nicholas' answer? Nicholas was in fact correct and was first. And why have you not answered any of our comment/questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhere you are creating a `Sprite` and passing the constructor a null image.  In your constructor try doing something like this

`if (image == null) throw new Exception("Cannot create Sprite with null image")`

Answer (score 5):

Check to see if image is null. That's most likely where the error is coming from.

Comment: But the image isn't null, because its been defined.

Comment: @Deza - Maybe you initialize it with `null` in the constructor.

Comment: The parameter image? You show that this.image.getWidth()/getHeight() is where the NPE is coming from, and the only logic solution is that either A) this is null, and that's never happening, or B) that image is null. this.image can be null if image is null.

Comment: @Deza: are you 100% sure? Have you called `println("image null?" + (image == null));` or something to that effect before the line of code   that throws the NPE?

Comment: Exactly what Hovercraft said. Check to see if image, and this.image are null(though they point to the same place). Do a simple print out. This is the only reason it would be throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

It would happen if `image` is `null`.  Somewhere in your code you must be making this call:

```
new Sprite(aFloat, anotherFloat, aNullValue); // aNullValue == null
```

You probably want to add some `null` checking in your constructor that throws a `RuntimeException`.  This will make it easy to find the code that is passing in a `null` `Image`.